# Can I rely on Google Lighthouse reports (especially for mobile sites)?

Tags: performance, mobile, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

We have started to use Lighthouse to track the improvements we make to our sites. While this seems to work quite well for desktop sites, i.e. we see the values improve over time and as we make changes, for mobile sites the values remain consistently low.  We do repeat the tests and use the best of three, but still.

Below, we have the results of the New York Times mobile site that *appears* to perform badly vis-a-vis the desktop site.  The other two are sites of ours, the main site and the third one being our own.

Browsing the site (as well as the NYT, of course) this apparent bad performance cannot be felt *at all*.

[image: comparison of our site (the last) with other high-profile sites]

The test procedure:

- run same test three times for each site
- mobile
- no PWA
- incognito mode

Now, while initially enthusiastic about Lighthouse's capability to evaluate a site by attributing aggregated figures that are easy to digest by management, we have the impression that they are not actually useful as they don't correspond to the users' reality and don't change even though we make changes.

Also, this being a Single Page Application, the first load of the page may take some more time, but any further navigation is quasi-instantaneous. We could not find a Lighthouse feature to take this into account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Comment: @JohnConde thanks for this. You're right. I was looking for an SEO-specific SE site and couldn't find one. I will close this one and repost on Webmaster.

Comment: @JohnConde I have reposted the question here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131720/can-i-rely-on-google-lighthouse-reports-especially-for-mobile-sites - As I don't have enough reputation to close my question, could you close it for me, please?

Comment: Removed the SEO tag for you, there is nothing wrong with your question here as there is actually nothing about SEO in it, but the community likes to close anything with the SEO tag on without reading it. You are in the right place to ask about Page Speed Insights don't worry.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719334/2702894) explains why you are seeing low scores. PSI uses [network throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md) that slows down the CPU and Network calls. If you want to see how your site performs after it has been cached (on first load of the page on second visit) you can use developer tools -> Lighthouse as that is the same engine as Page Speed Insights. You probably don't feel it as you have a decent phone / network connection, grab a mid-tier phone on 4G and you will see issues.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228181/2702894) explains how to run lighthouse locally while not wiping the cache each time. It also shows ways to test other scenarios using Lighthouse as a CLI. Finally the [Core Web Vitals](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) library from Google allows you to monitor your sites key metrics in the real world, as this is a SPA you may want to look into that. One last point - don't focus on the score, focus on everything under "opportunities", fix those if you are able, PSI is a tool and it's suggestions are more important than the score

Comment: ignore the parts about Page Speed Insights, the rest is valid I had misread your question.  The final part about "Core Web Vitals" library is your best bet to see "after initial load" performance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't really rely on Lighthouse. As you've observed, well known fast websites perform badly in tests. While there are some reasons for this, it won't help you measure the actual loading speed. Caching being an important factor. Lazy-loading sometimes is confused as not yet loaded. So even if your website is loaded, Lighthouse might detect missing pieces and deem it not yet loaded.

Pingdom is great for that, and provides you with the options to test different regions, which I believe to be more realistic than one server fits all.
Also the Legacy version of GTmetrix is great because it points you directly to what improvements you can make but it tests only from Canada (unless you buy the PRO version). It takes caching into account.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PSI for mobile on our sites and worked well. Atleast mobile score was always better than lab data & my motivation was report was consistent on some external sites like https://covid19.ca.gov/.

Coming to tool works well for initial load but does not take into affect for one page app since cls is continuous evaluation has user scroll through CLS changes that is not simulated in tool. That is where field data differs.

Thanks,